# How to use Sqlite android case when to perform different insert statement,

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am selecting a value from a select statement then i want to perform two different insert from different table.

```
   create trigger hello after insert on b
   begin    
    select tag from b;

       case when  result =0
       Then 
          insert a values("true");
        else
          insert c values("false");     
   end;
```

how can i achieve this trigger. the error is"
 Query Error: near "CASE": syntax error Unable to execute statement

Comment: Not sure if it still is needed in sqlite, but are you creating a seperate delimiter so `;` can be used inside of you're query? Don't forget you also have to end your case as well as the begin (you will need 2 ends)

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has no `CASE` statement; it only has a `CASE` expression that can be used inside other SQL statements.

In SQLite, [triggers must be written with pure `SELECT`/`INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` statements](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html), and anything you want to be done must be a side effect of those.

However, the `WHEN` clause allows conditional execution.
This only works for an entire trigger, so you need two of them:

```
CREATE TRIGGER hello_tag_0
AFTER INSERT ON b
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.tag = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO a VALUES('true');
END;

CREATE TRIGGER hello_tag_not0
AFTER INSERT ON b
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.tag <> 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO c VALUES('false');
END;
```